# How do I sort this custom list of sticky posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, sort

Here is my code, which gets me all the sticky posts in my site.

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($query->have_posts()) { //while loop starts
        $query->the_post();     
    ?>
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_ID();?></a>

    <?php
        $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
        $cats = array();  
        foreach($post_categories as $c){
            $cat = get_category( $c );
            $cats[] = $cat->slug;
        }
        foreach($cats as $cat){
            echo $cat;
        }
        echo '<br>';
    } //while loop ends
```

Right now it only displays the id of the post with link to the post AND the category-slug of the category to which the post belongs. Here is what the result looks like.

[image]

Now I need this list to be "ordered alphabetically" with the values of the "category-slug". So that it looks something like this.

[image]

Please let me know in comments if my question seems unclear or if I may have missed something. I do not need entire code (although that would be great ) but a suggestion or ideas on how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$ids_by_category = array();

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();          
    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID()); 
    foreach($post_categories as $c){
        $cat = get_category($c);
        $ids_by_category[$cat->slug][] = get_the_ID();
    }
}

// sort by key
ksort($ids_by_category);

foreach ($ids_by_category as $category_slug => $ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        printf(
            '<a href="%s">%d</a> %s<br>',
            get_permalink($id),
            $id,
            $category_slug
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ................./loopresult.php on line 29. Here is what is on line 29 `$ids_by_category[$cat->slug][] = $get_the_ID();`

Comment: My mistake, change `$get_the_ID();` to `get_the_ID();`